# Retrieving data using java matcher and pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to get an alphanumeric number from a string statement for eg. ***UN345690*** .I am using the below code.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
```

Please tell me what code should I use to get the desired result.

Comment: You've covered the "numeric" part, now you need to add the "alpha" part as well. How that should be done depends on your requirements, e.g. `UN\d+` might work if all numbers start with `UN`, otherwise you'd need something else. Also note that `"\d+"` wouldn't be a valid Java string - you'd need to escape the backslash, i.e. `"\\d+"`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to get an alphanumeric number

Since you already specified the regex `\d+` I assume you want to extract the ordinary number `345690` from `UN345690`. An *alpha*numeric number would also include letters; but it is unclear which letters would be allowed in that case and how you would differentiate between a regular word and an alphanumeric "number".

Use a `Matcher` to search for your pattern in a string, then retrieve the first match.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("UN345690");
if (matcher.find()) {
  String number = matcher.group();
  // do something with the extracted number
}
```